# LIMIT specialize

Tags: mysql, limit

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(parent, id) AS p, IFNULL(reply_comment_id, id) AS r
FROM article_comments ORDER BY p ASC, r ASC, date DESC
```

[image]

I want use LIMIT. If I have more row, I want limit the query by "p".
In image: ("p": 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) – this is ONE, ("p": 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2) – this is TWO...

For example, I want: if I use LIMIT 1, then only show ("p": 1, 1, 1, 1, 1).[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by `("p": 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)` and `("p": 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)` can you explain?

Comment: Isn't this what `where` is for? Why do you need a dynamic-limit clause that restricts you to a single value?

Comment: (reply_comment_id == NULL && parent == NULL) = comment to article
(reply_comment_id == NULL && parent != NULL) = comment to comment
(reply_comment_id != NULL && parent != NULL) = comment to comment comment

This all listend in one box. So, 1,1,1,1,1... is ONE box. I want limit BIG box numbers, which includes comment to article, comment to comment, comment to comment comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query I would use:

```
SELECT * FROM
FROM article_comments
WHERE id = 1 OR parent = 1
ORDER BY parent ASC, reply_comment_id ASC, `date` DESC
```

Note that I see no need for your calculated columns here.  When ordering by parent and reply_comment_id in ascending fashion, the NULL values will be first in sort.

Make sure you have indexes on parent, reply_comment_id, and date fields (in addition to id, which I assume is primary key)

Also, you might want to consider using a datetime field for your date column, rather than unix timestamp.  It is much user friendly when viewing the data in the database, as well as when trying to query date ranges/ So can write your filter like this:

```
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Instead of having to due timestamp conversions.

Comment: I uploaded a new image. What SQL query I posted is simplifies.
Other example: I want to show 4 BIG box, witch include 1,1,1,1;2,2,2,2;3,3,3,3,3;6,6,6,6 (if 4,5 is used in other article)

Comment: @bsz  I don't understand what you mean by `(if 4,5 is used in other article)`.  You should not worry about trying to decide how you are going to lay things out on the screen.  What you need to work on is understanding how SQL works, so you can better describe what you are looking for.  Also, these sort of trees structures might best be stored in a NoSQL database, but taht if something totally different altogether.